# Unable to copy svn repo to a new branch

Tags: svn

I currently have a SVN repo from which I want to create a branch.

My current svn info gives me:

```
user@node directory $ svn info
Path: .
URL: svn://10.169.99.170/ilab/trunk/master
Repository Root: svn://10.169.99.170/ilab
Repository UUID: 065c76b3-4556-42dd-b1f2-9738222b7d84
```

I am trying to create a new branch out of this and using the below command:

```
user@node dir $ svn copy svn://10.169.99.170/ilab/trunk/master    svn://10.169.99.170/ilab/branches/msd -m "Creating MSD branch"
svn: Path 'branches' not present
```

On my SVN server, my directory looks like:

```
[root@svnnode ilab]# ls -ltrh
total 28K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  229 Jun  7 14:52 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun  7 14:52 locks
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun  7 14:52 hooks
-r--r--r-- 1 root root    2 Jun  7 14:52 format
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun  7 14:53 conf
drwxr-sr-x 6 root root 4.0K Jul 15 17:08 db
```

Is there something that I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something that I am missing ?

Yes: you miss understanding "What was done", "What happened" and "What these errors means"

1. `ls -l` on repository filesystem is totally useless: you **must** to see at repository-tree, not FS, not `svn ls svn://10.169.99.170/ilab/` is uselss too: it can only confirm already shown in error-message "Path 'branches' not present"
2. Good branching policy in SVN is **full branching** of tree, not partial. For root `svn://10.169.99.170/ilab` you'll better to branch from `^/trunk`, not *subtree of trunk*
3. `svn help copy` give us hint for all possible and needed options: re-read it carefully and note "--parents : make intermediate directories" option, which will create (when used) all missing directories in copy-target